# Aggregate Join in MongoDB not returning results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, join

I am trying to do an aggregate join to find patient information in the 'patients' table based on 'patient_id' field in the bookings table. Aggregate join is not returning results even though there are matching records in the 'patients' table. Am I doing something wrong? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `_id` field in the "patients" collection is an ObjectId, it won't match when you compare to the string value stored in `patient_id`. You can use the `$addFields` aggregation step to add a new field to the documents with the "patient_id" field cast to an ObjectId, but I'd advise you to instead store reference id's as ObjectIds